# Extract used CSS including JavaScript

Tags: css

What is the best way to extract only the CSS used including those used by JavaScript.

I tried [CSS Usage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-usage/) seems to have stopped working with the current versions of firefox

[Dust-Me](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/) works but it classifies css used by javascript as unused css.

Comment: Are you trying to scrape the CSS, or access it via JS within a page? It looks like you're looking specifically for a Chrome extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newest version of Google Chrome [now has this feature built-in](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#coverage).

From the developer tools (press F12 to show them), there is now a new "Coverage" menu.

[image]

[image]

Simply start recording, reload the page, and then stop recording.

It will show JS/CSS coverage:

[image]

You can then click on an individual CSS files to see coverage details:

[image]

Comment: Very good, this seems to work correctly. Does it have any way to save only the used code or do I have to manually clean it?

Comment: @BrunoAndrade I don't believe there's a way to do that. The browser (Google Chrome) doesn't have write access to the actual source code files, just read access to a copy of it sent over the network.